# rails send empty message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Mailer:

```
class CustomerHistoryMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "notifications@example.com"
  def log_email(to)
    mail(:to => to,
         :subject => 'Report')
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class Admin::ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    CustomerHistoryMailer.log_email("me@example.com").deliver
  end
end
```

View (app/views/customer_history_mailer/log_email.text.erb):

```
Hello, world!
```

In my mailbox I receive empty message with right subject. Why?

Comment: What does your log file show you - some error/warning related to this email.

Comment: Nothing except `Started GET "/admin/reports/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2011-05-30 23:01:43 +0400` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `config.action_mailer.deprecation = :log` line from `config/environments/development.rb` and it works now.

Comment: I want but I site says 'You can accept your own answer tomorrow'

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you have generated a .html.rb view as well, and rails is detecting both, thus sending a multipart message (being the HTML empty) thus you are not seeing anything because your email client defaults to the HTML view?

Can you verify that?

--- What about specifying the order for html/text in the multipart msg?

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = user_url(@user)
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site") do |format|
      format.html
      format.text
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In `app/views/customer_history_mailer` there is only one view file, `log_email.text.erb`. I've already tried to replace this file to log_email.html.erb. No effect